# Xubuntu 14.04 says it's connected to wifi but is really slow and won't connect to any website as if there is no internet connection

Tags: wireless, xubuntu, firefox, internet

Like I said the wifi indicator says it's connected to the internet with like all of the bars (I'm right next to my wifi box) but, when I open up firefox, it won't connect to any website as if there was no internet connection. And when i go to install something in the ubuntu software center it acts likes it's going to install something and then it fails almost immediately. It's something to do with this particular netbook and/or xubuntu 14.04 install. Help?

Comment: Please, give us more details. Edit question and put output from command `route`, `host goggle.com` and `ping 8.8.8.8`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i kind of had a similar issue once. At work i had no problem with connecting to the web with my Xubuntu 12.04.4 installations, though at home my laptop connected to the but was super slow. I was fiddling about it for a couple of days and finally found out that my wifi adapter was in energy saving mode. Maybe its worth a try.